# C++ - Sort an 1-dimensional array to a 2-dimensional array with numbers in a range

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

My 1-dimensional array is for example: {21,23,24,45,43,63,65,66}.

The output array should be: {{21,23,24},{45,43},{63,65,66}}

Is it possible to write an algorithm which sorts the 1-dim array in a 2-dim array where the numbers in the subarrays are in a range of e.g 10. And is it maybe better to use vectors for that problem?

Comment: "Is it possible" - Certainly. "Is it better to use vectors" - Probably. What have you tried? It's hard to answer these really generic questions, but it gets much easier if you provide some code and the problem you ran into.

Comment: Depending on the range of input numbers, you might even choose sth. like `std::map<int, vector<int>>` to avoid the outer array to become very huge.

Comment: Is this your homework?

Answer (score 1):

assuming you use the map<int, vector<int>> you can do:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using bucket = std::map<int, std::vector<int>>;

bucket ToBucket(const std::vector<int>& input)
{
    bucket res;
    for (const auto& i : input)
    {
        res[i/10].push_back(i);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Afterwards you can sort the numbers in the vectors...